# Xamarin forms: How to make time picker to not allow past time being picked

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my project, I'm using **TimePicker** for choosing time. Using that I"m creating some events on my app.

My problem is when I open a TimePicker I need to disable the past time.

**For Example**, If the current time is 10:15 AM, I need to disable all the past time from 12 AM to 10:14 AM. Is there any property available for this kind of feature?

For **DatePicker** we have a property called `MinimumDate`. But I don't see anything similar for the time picker.

Comment: I think the easiest approach would be validate after the user selects a time.  Alternatively you could use a standard picker with a list of valid times in increments

Comment: If it isn't possible on the platform specific control (e.g. the Android clock picker widget) then it won't be possible on the Xamarin Forms control either. You can either do what Jason suggests and use the OnTimeSelected event to run some sort of validation, revert to using a standard Picker where you specify the list of items in the picker or a 3rd option would be to write custom renderers that use some kind of NumberPicker (on Android) where you specify your own options if you want a more native feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the save function for the event, (after choosing time) add validation for the time like below:

```
if ((DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < timePicker.Time)
{
     Debug.WriteLine("choosed time is future time");
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("choosed time is past time");
}
```

If the code is hitting the if block, the time picker has a future time and if it is on the else block the chosen time is from the past.